# Why Hibernate ignores not-null constraint?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have faced interesting behaviour of Hibernate. Can somebody explain me why this happens?

Technology stack: Java 11 / Spring boot [2.3.2.RELEASE] / Spring data [2.3.2.RELEASE] / Hibernate [5.4.18.Final].

I have a table created by liquibase:

```
<changeSet id="create-persons-table" author="author">
    <createSequence sequenceName="persons_seq"/>
    <createTable tableName="persons">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" defaultValueSequenceNext="persons_seq"/>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="lastname" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="es_identification" type="varchar(500)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="person_type" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

I have three entities. Base entity, common entity and country-specific entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_gen")
    private Long id;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "person_type")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen", sequenceName = "persons_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@DiscriminatorValue("ES")
@Getter
@Setter
public class EsPerson extends Person {
    @Column(name = "es_identification", nullable = false)
    private String esIdentification;
}
```

and I have corresponding repositories for them:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    Optional<T> findById(Long id);

    default T requireById(Long id) {
        checkNotNull(id, "id cannot be null");
        return findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }
}
```

```
public interface PersonRepository extends BaseRepository<Person> {
}
```

```
public interface EsPersonRepository extends BaseRepository<EsPerson> {
}
```

So the magic (for me) starts when I'm trying to save the EsPerson entity.

```
var person = new EsPerson();
person.setName("name");
person.setLastname("lastname");
person.setEsIdentification("es-identification");

esPersonRepository.save(esPerson);
```

In debug mode I see that all properties are not null.
But when I'm saving I've got `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column 'es_identification' violates not-null constraint`.

I have turned on sql logs and I see that hibernate INSERTs "name", "lastname" and null.
After that I've turned off not-null constraint on "es_identification" column and I see that Hibernate firstly INSERTs "name", "lastname", null and after that UPDATEs "es_identification" and sets corresponding value.

So this looks really strange for me. Why Hibernate does not inserts all values in one action? And why it ignores "not-null" constraint?

Please, keep in mind that it is big enough project, so maybe I have missed some important things here. Just trying to keep example as simple as possible.

Comment: *Why* Hibernate acts like that is an implementation-specific question. The bottom line is: not-null constraints are not allowed for single-table inheritance, and Hibernate is free to operate under that assumption

Comment: @crizzis thank you for the answer! I didn't know that non-null constraints are not allowed for single-table inheritance. Already found a proof that you are right! I could mark your answer as a correct if you move it from comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why* Hibernate acts like that is an implementation-specific question. The bottom line is: not-null constraints are not allowed for child properties in single-table inheritance, and Hibernate is free to operate under that assumption.

The reason is, of course, that the columns corresponding to child properties are necessarily `NULL` when inserting the parent entity record.